# Modal not working in dynamic flask website, all browsers

Tags: python, html, flask, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5

I am building a website in flask and have some issues with the function of a bootstrap modal. Confirmed the issue in Firefox, Chrome and Safari.

The user can select between three choices, A, B and C on the main route. The choices require slightly different forms. After submitting, the server queries the database and presents some data, still on the same route, if *result* is passed into the template, the page looks different and the user can then expand the data presented and move to read more. Here's where the issue happens, on the second modal. Before, no problems. Now tough, only the first modal in the for loop works as intended. All others just darken the screen, without showing the modal to the user. They look fine in the html source code.

Let's walk through the code. Here's the route.py, FormA, B and C are very similar (and work), I left the redundant code out. I think that the code on route.py is fine.

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import SubmitField, SelectField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired


class FormA(FlaskForm):
    selection_1 = SelectField(u'Selector 1', choices=['1.A', '1.B'], validators=[DataRequired()])
    selection_1 = SelectField(u'Selector 2', choices=['2.A', '2.B'], validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Submit!')

def database_query(one, two, three):
    # queries the database and returns values, that depend on the choices from form
    # code works and does not matter to the problem, thus is omited for brevity.
    return

@main.route('/', methods=["GET", "POST"])
@main.route('/home', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def home():
    choices = ['A', 'B', 'C', ]

    form_a = FormA()
    form_b = FormB()        # Form B and C are just like A, 
    form_c = FormC()        # but with different choices for selector 1 and 2

    if form_a.validate_on_submit():
        result, info = database_query('A', choices, form_a)
        return render_template('main/home.html', choices=choices,
                               form_a=form_a, form_b=form_b, form_c=form_c,
                               result=result, info=info)

    if form_b.validate_on_submit():
        result, info = database_query('B', choices, form_b)
        return render_template('main/home.html', choices=choices, 
                               form_a=form_a, form_b=form_b, form_c=form_c,
                               result=result, info=info)

    if form_c.validate_on_submit():
        result, info = database_query('C', choices, form_c)
        return render_template('main/home.html', choices=choices, 
                               form_a=form_a, form_b=form_b, form_c=form_c,
                               result=result, info=info)

    return render_template('main/home.html', choices=choices, form_a=form_a, form_b=form_b, form_c=form_c)
```

So, all that stuff works, the thing that's tripping me up and making me pull my hair out is the behaviour of a bootstrap modal using bootstrap 5.1. On the first go through return render+template, when I pass in choices instead of result, all's good. Here's the html template, of course there's much more in here, I removed all the stuff that doesn't matter to the problem at hand:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
    {% if result %}
       {% for item in result %}  <!-- MODAL RESULT WORKS ONLY FOR VERY FIRST item in for, not any since -->
            <a class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" style="float:right;" href="#"
                            data-bs-toggle="modal"
                            data-bs-target="#modal-{{item.id}}">Expand</a>

        {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
        {% for choice in choices %}   <!-- MODAL CHOICE WORKS FINE -->
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary"       
                            data-bs-toggle="modal"
                            data-bs-target="#Choice-{{ choice }}">Select</a>
        {%endfor%}
    {% endif %}


<!-- Modal -->
{% if result %}<!-- Modal on second round -->
  {% for item in result %}<!-- Modal to display lens information -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="modal-{{item.id}}" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="enrollLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="modal-{{item.id}}-title">{{item.property}}</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <!-- REMOVED -->
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
  {% endfor %}
{% else %}<!-- Modal to select format -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="Choice-A" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="enrollLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title">Header</h5>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <!-- REMOVED -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal fade" id="Choice-B" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="enrollLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title">Header</h5>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <!-- REMOVED -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal fade" id="Choice-C" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="enrollLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title">Header</h5>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <!-- REMOVED -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
{% endif %}
{% endblock content %}
```

And finally, some source html from the browser. The loop works and displays the modals as intended, at the end of the file but there's no functionality. modal-1 works fine, all the others only darken the screen. I don't get why, what am I missing? Thank!

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
       <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link
          rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.3.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css"
        />
        <link
          href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.1.1/mapbox-gl.css"
          rel="stylesheet"
        />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/main.css" />
        <title></title>
      </head>
      <body>

        



      <!-- Main Content, Grid Boxes -->
      <section class="bg-light p-3 p-lg-5 p-md-4">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="wrapper px-5 px-md-3">
            
              <div class="card bg-secondary text-dark" style="--bs-bg-opacity: .4;">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <a class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" style="float:right;" href="#"
                                  data-bs-toggle="modal"
                                  data-bs-target="#modal-1">More</a>
                  </div>
                </div>

              
                       
                <div class="card bg-secondary text-dark" style="--bs-bg-opacity: .4;">
                  <div class="card-body card-grid-wrap">
                    <a class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" style="float:right;" href="#"
                                data-bs-toggle="modal"
                                data-bs-target="#modal-130">More</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              
                <div class="card bg-secondary text-dark" style="--bs-bg-opacity: .4;">
                  <div class="card-body card-grid-wrap">
                    <a class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" style="float:right;" href="#"
                                data-bs-toggle="modal"
                                data-bs-target="#modal-23">More</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              
                <div class="card bg-secondary text-dark" style="--bs-bg-opacity: .4;">
                  <div class="card-body card-grid-wrap">
                    <a class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" style="float:right;" href="#"
                                data-bs-toggle="modal"
                                data-bs-target="#modal-14">More</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              
                <div class="card bg-secondary text-dark" style="--bs-bg-opacity: .4;">
                  <div class="card-body card-grid-wrap">
                    <a class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" style="float:right;" href="#"
                                data-bs-toggle="modal"
                                data-bs-target="#modal-15">More</a>
                  </div>
                </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
              
    <!-- REMOVED -->        

      <!-- Modal -->
        <!-- Modal to display more information -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="modal-1" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="enrollLabel" aria-hidden="true">
           <!-- REMOVED -->
        </div>
       <!-- Modal to display more information -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="modal-130" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="enrollLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <!-- REMOVED -->
        </div>
        <!-- Modal to display more information -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="modal-23" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="enrollLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <!-- REMOVED -->
        </div>
        <!-- Modal to display more information -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="modal-14" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="enrollLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <!-- REMOVED -->
        </div>
        <!-- Modal to display more information -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="modal-15" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="enrollLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <!-- REMOVED -->
        </div>

        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-U1DAWAznBHeqEIlVSCgzq+c9gqGAJn5c/t99JyeKa9xxaYpSvHU5awsuZVVFIhvj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.1.1/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
        <script>
          mapboxgl.accessToken =
            'pk.eyJ1IjoiYnRyYXZlcnN5IiwiYSI6ImNrbmh0dXF1NzBtbnMyb3MzcTBpaG10eXcifQ.h5ZyYCglnMdOLAGGiL1Auw'
          var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
            container: 'map',
            style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
            center: [-71.060982, 42.35725],
            zoom: 18,
          })
        </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. There was an unclosed `<div>` tag. Putting that in, solved the issue. Works as intended now.